# Correct use of $.when - done

Tags: javascript, jquery, deferred, .when

I have a search function in a gallery that works by checking the search term against certain fields in a nested JSON. So far, it finds the terms I enter and returns an alert if it is not found. So the search works correctly in that sense, like so:

```
$(document).on('click', '#searchBtn', function (e) {
        var searchTerm = $('#searchTerm').val();
        for (var i = 0; i < data.category.length; i++) {
            if (data.category[i].categoryName.split('<--name-->')[currentLang] === searchTerm) {
                console.log('found: ' + searchTerm + ' ' + data.category[i].categoryId);
                return populateResults(data.category[i].categoryId);
            }
            for (var j = 0; j < data.category[i].subcategory.length; j++) {
                if (data.category[i].subcategory[j].subcategoryName.split('<--name-->')[currentLang] === searchTerm) {
                    console.log('found: ' + searchTerm + ' ' + data.category[i].subcategory[j].subcategoryId);
                    return populateResults(data.category[i].subcategory[j].subcategoryId);
                }
                for (var k = 0; k < data.category[i].subcategory[j].imgs.length; k++) {
                    if (data.category[i].subcategory[j].imgs[k].imgName.split('<--name-->')[currentLang] === searchTerm) {
                        console.log('found: ' + searchTerm + ' ' + data.category[i].subcategory[j].imgs[k].imgId);
                        return populateResults(data.category[i].subcategory[j].imgs[k].imgId);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        alert('Search term not found');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

However, when it finds an entry it is supposed to take you to the specific entry by simulating mouseovers (which trigger the GETting of the text and pushes it into an array of loaded texts) and a click (which passes the text to an overlay):

```
function populateResults(searchId) {
        homeMenu();
        if (searchId.length === 1) {
            $('#' + searchId).mouseover();
            $('#' + searchId).click();
        }
        else if (searchId.length === 3) {
            $.when(
                    $('#' + searchId[0]).mouseover(),
                    $('#' + searchId[0]).click()
                    ).done(function () {
                $('#' + searchId).mouseover();
                $('#' + searchId).click();
            });
        }
        else if (searchId.length === 5) {
            ....
        }
        else {
            alert('Search malfuncion!');
        }
    }
```

The problem is that when you search with a clear cache it will return with the wrong values (due to the fact that it hasn't pushed the values into the loaded text array which happens on hover). The second time you search for the same thing it will provide the right info, but I'm trying (as you can see in the first else if statement in the populateResults function) to make the application wait until the mouseover trigger has pushed the info before clicking on the next level down). So far I've had no luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: Note 1: `populateResults` is a `void` function (not return type), so your multiple `return populateResults(...)`s make no sense. Also returning anything other than `true` or `false` makes no sense inside a `click` event handler.

Comment: $.when isn't even doing anything. Nothing in your code returns promises. Trying to call mousover in a recursive function seems very unorthodox also

Comment: Note 2: `$.when` takes promises/deferreds as arguments. You are passing jQuery objects.

Comment: See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when _"If a single argument is passed to jQuery.when() and it is not a Deferred or a Promise, it will be treated as a resolved Deferred and any doneCallbacks attached will be executed immediately. The doneCallbacks are passed the original argument. In this case any failCallbacks you might set are never called since the Deferred is never rejected."_ If possible , can create stacksnippets / jsfiddle ? including `html`, `css`, `js` ?

Comment: The returns are meant to stop the function when it does find a match instead of falling to the "search term not found" alert. I will look into the API as suggested and attempt to pass deferreds instead of objects. Thanks!